# ReactJS seems combine two state updates as one render, how to see separate rendering effects?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to come up a react exercise for the flip-match cards game: say 12 pairs of cards hide (face down) randomly in a 4x6 matrix, player click one-by-one to reveal the cards, when 2 cards clicked are match then the pair is found, other wise hide both again., gane over when all pairs are found.

```
let stored = Array(I * J).fill(null).map((e, i) => (i + 1) % (I * J));
/* and: randomize (I * J / 2) pairs position in stored */

class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cards: Array(I*J).fill(null),
            nClicked: 0,
            preClicked: null,
            clicked: null,
        };
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        if (!this.state.cards[i]) {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                const upCards = prevState.cards.slice();
                upCards[i] = stored[i];
                return {
                    cards: upCards,
                    nClicked: prevState.nClicked + 1,
                    preClicked: prevState.clicked,
                    clicked: i,
                };
            }, this.resetState);
        }
    }

    resetState() {
        const preClicked = this.state.preClicked;
        const clicked = this.state.clicked;
        const isEven = (this.state.nClicked-1) % 2;
        const matched = (stored[preClicked] === stored[clicked]);
        if (isEven && preClicked && clicked && matched) {
            // this.forceUpdate(); /* no effects */
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                const upCards = prevState.cards.slice();
                upCards[preClicked] = null;
                upCards[clicked] = null;
                return {
                    cards: upCards,
                    nClicked: prevState.nClicked,
                    preClicked: null,
                    clicked: null,
                };
            });
        }
    }

    renderCard(i) {
        return <Card key={i.toString()} value={this.state.cards[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Cards: '+ I + ' x ' + J +', # of clicked: ' + this.state.nClicked;
        const cardArray = Array(I).fill(null).map(x => Array(J).fill(null));
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                    { cardArray.map((element_i, index_i) => (
                        <div key={'row'+index_i.toString()} className="board-row">
                            { element_i.map((element_j, index_j) => this.renderCard(index_i*J+index_j))
                            }
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Essentially, Board constructor initialize the state, and handleClick() calls setState() to update the state so it trigger the render of the clicked card's value; the callback function resetState() is that if the revealed two card did not match, then another setState() to hide both.

The problem is, the 2nd clicked card value did not show before it goes to hide. Is this due to React combine the 2 setState renderings in one, or is it rendering so fast that we can not see the first rendering effects before the card goes hide? How to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you throw a debugger in there?  Can you see the two states?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing resetState as the callback to setState, so I would expect after the initial click your state will be reset.

You might want to simplify a bit and do something like this:

```
const CARDS = [
    { index: 0, name: 'Card One', matchId: 'match1' },
  { index: 1, name: 'Card Two', matchId: 'match2' },
  { index: 2, name: 'Card Three', matchId: 'match1', },
  { index: 3, name: 'Card Four', 'matchId': 'match2' },
];

class BoardSim extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      cardsInPlay: CARDS, 
      selectedCards: [],
      checkMatch: false,
      updateCards: false
    };
    ...
  }

  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!prevState.checkMatch && this.state.checkMatch) {
        this.checkMatch();
    }

    if (!prevState.updateCards && this.state.updateCards) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.mounted && this.updateCards();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  handleCardClick(card) {
    if (this.state.checkMatch) {
        return;
    }

    if (this.state.selectedCards.length === 1) {
        this.setState({ checkMatch: true });
    }

    this.setState({
        selectedCards: this.state.selectedCards.concat([card])
    });
  }

  checkMatch() {
    if (this.selectedCardsMatch()) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.mounted && this.setState({ updateCards: true });
    }, 2000);
  }

  selectedCardsMatch() {
    return this.state.selectedCards[0].matchId === 
    this.state.selectedCards[1].matchId;
  }

  updateCards() {
    let cardsInPlay = this.state.cardsInPlay;
    let [ card1, card2 ] = this.state.selectedCards;
    if (this.selectedCardsMatch()) {
       cardsInPlay = cardsInPlay.filter((card) => {
           return card.id !== card1.id && card.id !== card2.id;
       });
    }

    this.setState({
      selectedCards: [],
      cardsInPlay,
      updateCards: false,
      checkMatch: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
           {this.renderCards()}
        </div>
    );
  }

  renderCards() {
    return this.state.cardsInPlay.map((card) => {
        return (
        <div key={card.name} onClick={() => this.handleCardClick(card)}>
            {card.name}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

I've created a fiddle for this you can check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgrewell/69z2wepo/82425/

Comment: I don't think it will work or it makes any difference:if you resetState() as is, it will not show the player what value the second card it; then you want change resetState to first show the card value, then hide both. My question is how to do that as React seems combine both in one render, or the two renders are so fast that we cannot see the first render effect before the 2nd effect kicks in?

Comment: Updated answer since it seems you're wondering about how to transition the states

Comment: Thanks. I did try to use componentDidUpdate() for getting the transition effect but that seems not working, maybe due to I did not programmed it correctly - you example give me a good hint, will try that again.